# Is there a way to make file operations look like in Windows?

Tags: files, linux-mint, mate-desktop, panel

Linux Mint 18.2, MATE.

For example, I am copying some files from one place to another. It is quite hard to notice errors or see how many files left while a window of this file operation is minimized.

[image]

In Windows data copying process displays in a minimized window in the panel by means of a green strip, or a minimized window changes its color because of some error.

[image]

Is there a way to do something similar in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options here are pretty limited.  The [Icon Tasks widget](https://store.kde.org/p/999206/) for KDE has this functionality, but the only application I know for sure makes use of its progress feature is Dolphin (file manager).  Hopefully this will expand to native DE implementations by some standard, as this is one of the few things I miss from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in MATE Desktop that's not possible, but you could try to request this feature in [GitHub](https://github.com/mate-desktop) for example in the [Caja](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja) or in the [MATE panel](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel) repository.